# Attempt to publish Azure Function App (python) fails with repository does no longer have a release file error

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I have a python azure function app that runs locally, and has previously been published OK to Azure via the following command:

```
(.env) PS C:\temp\python_function> func azure functionapp publish httpgengraph --build-native-deps --publish-local-settings -i
```

However I have tried just now and got errors that mean very little to me (I can't find any information online specifically about these errors during publishing an azure function).

```
E: The repository 'https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/9/prod stretch Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security jessie/updates Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--build-native-deps` uses a docker container to build your Python Function App. I have seen this error before if your docker is running low on space/memory.

You can try to run any debian docker container and run `apt-get update. For example-

```
docker run -d mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python
docker exec -it <image-id-from-last-command> /bin/bash`
apt-get update
```

I bet this would give you similar errors.

To fix this problem, try to delete unused stopped docker containers. 
You can use `docker system prune -a` to remove all stopped containers. I would advise double checking to make sure those aren't being used somewhere else.

If you still see issues after clearing some allocated space, let me know.

Comment: Hi Ankit, I checked and have no containers stopped or otherwise: (.env) PS C:\temp\python_function> docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES.     I'm a beginner with Python and thought I needed the build-native-deps switch to ensure my non-standard Python packages get included in the build? Is that correct? I'm going to try again now and see what happens. Will advise if same result.

Comment: I tried without the switch and predictably got this error: There was an error restoring dependencies.ERROR: cannot install uuid-1.30 dependency: binary dependencies without wheels are not supported.  Use the --build-native-deps option to automatically build and configure the dependencies using a Docker container. More information at https://aka.ms/func-python-publish

Comment: Accepting this as the answer, as it was but just needed a different line of remediation. After restarting my PC I noticed Docker had a low memory error (and couldn't start). I have reduced the usable memory set down to 1GB, restarted, and now it appears the function is publishing OK. Very strange error to get as a result of low memory however! Thanks Ankit!